# Is there a way to access the second event parameter in knockout keypress binding without declaring the data parameter first?

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, event-handling

I am using Knockout/Typescript in a project and would like to access the second 'event' parameter after a keypress event, but do not need to use the first 'data' parameter.

Typescript throws an error on build when I have an unused 'data' local variable. Is there a way to access the keypress event without first declaring the data parameter?

For example:
HTML

```
<a data-bind="event: { keypress: onKeyPressFunction }"></a>
```

JavaScript

```
var onKeyPressFunction = (data: any, event: any): void => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // do something
    else {
        // do something else
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to suppress the 'error' is to start the variable with an underscore (or just use an underscore by itself).

"[Parameters declaration with names starting with _ are exempt from the unused parameter checking.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9458)"

```
var onKeyPressFunction = (_: any, event: any): void => {
...
}
```

See also [--noUnusedParameters how can i skip uneeded parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9458) and the --`noUnusedParameters` flag in [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).